# Bit twiddling, off by one error

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <bitset>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        int k = -1;
        int v = -1;
        int r = 0;
        for(int s = 0; s <= 30 ; s++){
            int vbit = v & 1;
            v >>= 1;
            r |= vbit;
            r <<= 1;
        }
        int vbit = v & 1;
        r |= vbit;
        cout << bitset<32>(k) << "  " << bitset<32>(r) << endl;
    }
```

I have written a code to reverse the bits in a integer. I my code works perfectly fine if I run the code as written but I think that I am looping one time less than I should to get to the correct answer. I have to shift 31 times to access all the bits in the int and the last two line of code after for loop is to patch the last bits to their places.
Is there a conceptual problem or a silly mistake?

Comment: Try mapping bit 0 to 31 and 31 to 0, then 1 to 30, 30 to 1 and so on, iterating over the range 0..15 and doing two swaps each time.

Comment: Look what happens if you try to reverse, say, 8, instead of -1. Your logic is wrong.

Comment: ...Wait... *Which* integer are you trying to reverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the shift to r before adding vbit to it.

That way you can shift 32 times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it that works for any unsigned integer type. (unsigned because it is undefined behavior to left shift a negative number, so using unsigned forces the caller to be sure the value is non-negative)

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto reverse_bits(T value) -> T
{
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned<T>::value, "type must be unsigned integer");

    constexpr auto digits = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits;

    T result = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < digits; ++k)
        result |= ((value >> k) & 0x01) << (digits - (k + 1));
    return result;
}
```